# Display content if on a certain page

Tags: php, html, symfony

I have an app I have been building in symfony and I am trying to only display content when the user is on a certain page. I have a if/else block (shown below) but the content still displays on the page I do not what it too. Am I doing this the wrong way?

the if else block

```
{% block nav %}
    {% set uri = app.request.uri %}
    {% if uri != 'login' %}
        {% include "StarnesUserBundle::user-nav.html.twig" %}
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

so it is supposed to display the `user-nav.html.twig` on every page that is not the `/login` page.

Comment: Do you use a specific Twig file for the login page?

Comment: @n.1 yes I have a seperate twig file for the login.

Comment: Ok, I added another solution, using a variable defined only in the separate file for the login page, but I won't post it since the other answer worked for you.

Comment: @n.1 actually I thought it worked but it did not work. Please post it

Comment: Please show how you include the layout from the login page and another random page.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Define a variable in the Twig template of the login page:

```
{% set hide_user_nav = true %}
```

Add a test for this variable in your layout:

```
{% if (hide_user_nav is not defined) %}
    {% block nav %}
        {% include "StarnesUserBundle::user-nav.html.twig" %}
    {% endblock %}
{% endif %}
```

Comment: unfortunately this did not work. This snippet of code is in a `layout.html.twig` and all user pages extend this layout. Would that stop it from working?

Comment: This dit not work because the user nav is always or never displayed?

Comment: it is never displayed

Comment: That's strange, it should always display, unless `hide_user_nav` is defined, which is never going to happen if you didn't use `{% set = … %}`.

Comment: Did you cleaned the cache?

Comment: yes i cleared the cache. Is there any other code you need to see? I can add anything.

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/44984/discussion-between-zachstarnes-and-n-1)

Answer (score 1):

Something like this should do the trick.  this is untested, but should give you a general idea.

```
{% block nav %}
    {% if app.request.attributes.get('_route') != 'login' %}
        {% include "StarnesUserBundle::user-nav.html.twig" %}
    {% endif %}
{% endblock %}
```

This assumes your `/login` route name is `login`, so just replace `login` with the name of your route

Comment: unfortunately the routes are not named like that. For example the route name for '/login' is `fos_user_security_login`

Answer (score 0):

If the login page extends the layout page that contains this block then you could just put an empty

```
{% block nav %}{% endblock nav %}
```

that would override the parent nav block.